# Output formatting Year Month Number

Tags: php

I have the following function

```
$incident_Id = mysql_insert_id ();
```

This function outputs numbers in a sequential form.

I would like to output the number in this format:

- year, then
- month, then
- the number of the incident.

Comment: echo date('Ym') . $incident_Id;

Answer (score 0):

You can simply merge it with the date function like below.

```
$incident_Id = date("Ym").mysql_insert_id ();

echo $incident_Id;
```